# SVN - rename root folder

Tags: svn, rename

To rename a folder in a working copy, we can run `svn mv`. But when you try to rename the root folder, you end up with

```
svn: E155007: '/home/username/svn_repos' is not a working copy
```

Where 'svn_repos' is where I'm storing all my individual repositories (one for each course). Unfortunately, when I check out my course repository, the name of the root folder is my university ID, since the svn structure is host/course/user. I want to rename it to the course code so that it is easier to navigate. How can I do that?

Comment: You could try it directly on the repository (supplying URLs as arguments) but I haven't actually tried this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the repos are contained *within* that folder, you can simply `mv` the root folder.  As it tells you, it's not tracked ("not a working copy") and changes to the container won't do anything that matters to the contents.  As long as your `.svn` is within that folder.

Comment: Woah, did not expect that. Thanks!

Comment: And btw, I'm not trying to rename the `svn_repos` folder, but the repo within that. So I checked out host/course/user, and the root folder was "user", which I renamed to "course". That worked fine too